# http tls server (golang) not working with curl

Tags: http, ssl, curl, go

So I'm trying to secure some REST API with TLS + http basic auth (I know it's not the best option but will start with and maybe move to OAuth later). Here is what I did:

- Generate cert and key with generate_cert.go. This gives cert.pem and key.pem
- In the server code, I used `ListenAndServeTLS()` with no extra option.
- So I fired up browser and go to https://localhost:8000. After adding an certificate exception, it works fine.

Now I have a few shell scripts for testing purpose using `curl`. I tried

```
curl -i --cacert cert.pem https://localhost:8000
```

and fully expected to see some JSON dump but all I got was the following error message:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Am I doing it wrong? If so, how can I use curl for this purpose?